# Which parentheses cause creating a subshell?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

So if I use `if` comamand like below, it's creating a subshell:

```
if ! (ffmpeg -h > /dev/null 2>&1)
then
    echo "FFmpeg NOT INSTALLED"
.
.
.
fi
```

What is about `var=$(<command>)` and its equivalent `` var=`<command>` `` ? Will they create a subshell either?

Comment: Yes, command substitutions like `a=$(...)` do create a subshell. In `bash`, a subshell always runs as a separate process. You don't need a subshell in your `ffmpeg` example -- it will work the same without the parens.

Comment: Backticks and `$(...)` are not entirely equivalent. The backticks do not, for example, nest.

Comment: @Kusalananda backticks of course do nest if you do it correctly. There is still a real difference: with backticks, the strings are fed two times though the parser and this may  unexpectedly remove backslashes.

Comment: @schily Maybe I should have written "don't nest in the same way as the other variant of command substitution does". The point being that they are not "equivalent" in the sense of "you can just replace `$(` and `)` with backticks".

Comment: @Kusalananda The important thing is that `echo $(grep -l '\\n' *c)` gives a different result in case you use backticks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both forms of command substitution create subshells.

[3.5.4 Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment

Answer (score 0):

If you avoid the old and hard to quote back tick command substitution.

Then the rule is simple periphrasis `()` create a sub-shell. However brackets `{}` do not.

- `()` subshell
- `$()` subshell and substitution
- `{}` no-subshell bracketing
- `${}` variable substitution

Comment: It gets a bit more complicated when you consider `while` and `for` etc.